# Requests that contains @ do not work

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've setup a quick search function for a database we have at work. Basically you search for an e-mail address, and you will get hits based on the email.

At the moment it works fine, I can for instance write `anna`, and get hits like `anna@thedomain.com`. It also works if I would've searched for `thedomain.com`.

But the second I write "anna@" I get "no hits". Ergo when I include the @ in my search field, I just don't get any hits.

The script is based on `index.html` which has some `js` attached to it, and the `search.php` script.

Here are the code for the `index.html`:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Live search</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- Load CSS -->
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Load Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:regular,bold" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Load jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load custom js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <!-- Title -->
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <h1 class="title">Search</h1>
        <h5 class="title">Find relevant data</h5>

        <!-- Input -->
        <input type="text" id="search" value="E-Mailaddress" onfocus="this.value = ''; return true" onblur="this.value = 'E-Mailaddress'; return true" autocomplete="off">

        <!-- Shows The result -->
        <h4 id="results-text">Showing results for: <b id="search-string">Array</b>    </h4>
            <ul id="results"></ul>


        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

---

The `search.php` script:

---

```
<?php
/************************************************
    The Search PHP File
************************************************/


/************************************************
    MySQL Connect
************************************************/
// Credentials
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "dbname";
$dbuser = "dbuser";
$dbpass = "dbpassword";

//  Connection
global $tutorial_db;

$tutorial_db = new mysqli();
$tutorial_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);


//  Check Connection
if ($tutorial_db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $tutorial_db->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/************************************************
    Search Functionality
************************************************/

// Define Output HTML Formating
$html = '';
$html .= '<li class="result">';
$html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';
$html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
$html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
$html .= '</a>';
$html .= '</li>';

// Get Search
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

// Check Length More Than One Character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    // Build Query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Emailaddress LIKE '%".$search_string."%'";

    // Do Search
    $result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
    while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array[] = $results;
    }

    // Check If We Have Results
    if (isset($result_array)) {
        foreach ($result_array as $result) {

            // Just a normal output
            $output = "<li>$result[Dataentry] / <a href='showmore.php?ticketid=$result[ticketref]'>Go to ticket</a> / <strong>$result[Emailaddress]</strong></li>";

            // Output
            echo $output;
        }
    }
    else{

        // Format No Results Output
        $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
        $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>Ingen resultater...</b>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);

        // Output
        echo($output);
    }
}


/*
// Build Function List (Insert All Functions Into DB - From PHP)

// Compile Functions Array
$functions = get_defined_functions();
$functions = $functions['internal'];

// Loop, Format and Insert
foreach ($functions as $function) {
    $function_name = str_replace("_", " ", $function);
    $function_name = ucwords($function_name);

    $query = '';
    $query = 'INSERT INTO search SET id = "", function = "'.$function.'", name = "'.$function_name.'"';

    $tutorial_db->query($query);
}
*/
?>
```

---

### the included `custom.js` file:

```
/* JS File */

// Start Ready
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }

    $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });

});
```

---

`index.html`, `search.php` & `custom.js` are all encoded in `utf-8`, and my database is `utf8_general_ci`.

Can anyone see why this won't work? I'm new to JavaScript, and have a feeling that there's a problem in the `JS`.

Comment: what do you get in `console.log(html);` after the ajax call come back success?

Comment: The line `$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query'])` converts `"anna@"` to `"anna "`.

Comment: using inspect element in Chrome, in Networks tab, check the response and the parameters you have in this ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line (as already mentioned by [DCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233508/dcoder) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289813/requests-that-contains-do-not-work/18290128#comment26832851_18289813))

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
```

replaces all characters except `A-Z`, `a-z` and `0-9` by an empty space.

Add the *@* symbol to the excluded characters:

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9@]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
```

Comment: Looks like you got in there 5 seconds before me :)

Comment: @JoeBuckle But you still got the answer mark ;)

Answer (score 2):

Might be a problem in your regex. You are stripping all non alpha characters which includes @. You can try the following, leaving @ out of the regex.

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9@]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
```